# Indexing ID after we created a new table with primary key ID

Tags: sql-server, database, indexing

Since the table will have primary key `id`, Microsoft SQL Server will automatically make it as the clustered index upon creation.

Does it mean that it's already optimized right from the start whenever we do queries like `Select * from tableX where id = 1` ?

Comment: Your question is tagged `mysql` but you ask about `MSSQL`. Can you edit the question and choose correct tags?

Comment: I think that this link can help you: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/68639/identity-column-as-clustured-index-bad-idea

Comment: A) Add your table definition to the question. B) What do you mean by "optimized"?